# Unable to click element in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following element in html:

```
<div class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio SelectStyle col"><label for="input_radio_style_4" aria-hidden="false" class=""><span class="c-form-label-content"><span class="c-image product c-image--square"><span class="LazyLoad is-visible"><img src="https://images.example.com/is/image/EBFL2/T4144300?wid=88&amp;hei=88&amp;fmt=png-alpha" alt="Teal/White | World Hood" id="T4144300"></span></span></span></label><input name="style" aria-labelledby="styleT4144300" id="input_radio_style_4" type="radio" required="" value="4"></div>
```

There's a bunch of these so here is my code to loop:

```
const styleElements = await page.$$('.SelectStyle');
```

I then map through each one to find a specific tag:

```
styleElements.map(async styEl => {
    try {
      const isThisStyle = await styEl.$eval(`img[alt="${prodOption}"]`, img => img);
      if(isThisStyle) {
        await styEl.$('input', input => input.click());
        await styEl.click();
      }
      // await styEl.click();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

The loop gives an error when the element does not match, which is ok but then when it is the element it doesn't click.  I tried two different options:

```
    await styEl.$('input', input => input.click());
    await styEl.click();
```

Any idea why the element is not being selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no idea how to solve this issue with an `array.map`, but a simple `for` loop works fine. As *map* returns an array with the same length as the original it is unnecessary here, we only need to click on the elements that match the required condition.

Also the context of the clicks should remain the `page`, we shouldn't go inside the element handle (`styEl` in your script), hence I decided to go for a loop, the index of the element is more useful in this usecase than returning something with each iteration.

1. We can check the actual `<img>`'s `alt` in the for loop with each iteration.
2. Check if they are equal to the `prodOption`.
3. If they are, then we can grab the handle of the current `<input>` on the very same index as the matching alt tag...
4. ...and click on it.

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < styleElements.length; i++) {
    try {
      const currentAlt = await page.evaluate(el => el.alt, (await page.$$('.SelectStyle img'))[i])
      if (currentAlt === prodOption) {
        const currentHandle = await page.$$('.SelectStyle input')
        await currentHandle[i].click()
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer cause this seems the correct way.  However I'm still not getting it to activate when I click.  When I inspect the element it changes the class to this: c-form-field c-form-field--radio c-form-field--checked c-form-field--focused SelectStyle col.  I'm wondering if it's not the input that has to be clicked?  Any ideas what it could be?  @theDavidBarton

Comment: I think the click on the <input> should select the option in all cases. Are you sure the ‘styleElements’ array contains all ‘.SelectStyle’ divs? Maybe due to lazyloading you need to wait a bit more to have all of them in the DOM (e.g.: force a ‘await page.waitFor(5000);’ after opening the page. I’ve tested it by copy-pasting your example to a plain HTML document so it is true: I did not needed to deal with lazyloading or slow rendering.